# Python: Using Multiprocessing Pool from an Imported Module

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ipython, python-3.5, pool

I am using Python 3.5 on the Anaconda-Spyder platform in Windows 7 environment. 
In test1.py, I have a method in a class that executes multiprocessing pool:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

class calc(object):        
    def run(self):  
        with Pool() as pool:
            g = pool.map(f,[0,1,2,7])
        print(g)
        return g
```

In test2.py, I create a class instance and call it to execute multiprocessing:

```
import importlib
imp = importlib.import_module('test1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = imp.calc()
    output = c.run()
```

It appears I am in a infinite loop; i.e. the (iPython) Console is running, but no output is generated. How can I get this to work properly? To hide executional details, I prefer to call a function that executes multiprocessing in another module.

Comment: When I run it (Python 3.5.2, Win10), it displays `[0, 1, 4, 49]` & terminates normally.  Can't guess what "infinite loop" means to you - you get no output at all?  You get a seemingly infinite amount of output?  You get some output and then it hangs? ...?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Would also be good to know why you're mucking with `importlib` instead of just doing `import test1 as imp`.

Comment: Whether it's imp = importlib.import_modeule('test') or import test1 as imp doesn't make any difference on my part. 

What I am encountering is that no output is ever generated by the (IPython) Console, yet it is running (the indicator is red).

Comment: I added an IPython tag, since that's probably relevant.  Try it from "a DOS box" (that's what I did, and it worked fine).  Note that the docs say:  "Functionality within this package requires that the `__main__` module be importable by the children. ... This means that some examples, such as the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` examples will not work in the interactive interpreter."

Comment: You are right, Tim. It works in "a DOS box". This is weird and makes it inconvenient. I hope in the future this issue can be addressed with interactive interpreters. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I can't help more - I simply don't use IPython.  But the behavior is pretty much the same across all "development environments", including IDLE (the basic IDE that ships with Python).  If I were you, I'd ask on an IPython list, or open an issue on the IPython issue tracker:  https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues